# Alternative Solutions for Syncing PostgreSQL Databases Across Machines

Tags: django, postgresql, openshift, rsync

I possess two machines:

1. My laptop, which operates on Ubuntu 22.04.
2. OKD (Openshift container) that runs on CentOS 7.

My objective is to synchronize a PostgreSQL database between these two machines.

Initially, I planned to utilize Rsync to ensure that the PostgreSQL data directory remains consistent on both machines. However, this method is likely to fail due to the differences in configuration files between the two systems.

An alternative approach involves using the `psql_dump` command to export the database from one machine and then importing it on the other.

Are there any other solutions available for scenarios like this (Note that this database is used for a Django project)?

Answer (score 3):

`django-pg-copy` was written for this purpose. It uses the credentials in your `DATABASES` settings to backup and restore Postgres databases across environments, such as backing up production to restore to dev.

https://pypi.org/project/django-pg-copy/

Full disclosure: I maintain this package.

Comment: Right now, I have problem installing new python packages on Openshift container. After solving that problem, I will let you know if it worked. Thank you.